# Can I have a washer, electric dryer, oil tank, and oil burner all in the same room?

Tags: dryer, boiler, washer

Is it safe to have the washer and an electric dryer in a basement room with an oil tank, oil burner for water baseboards and water heater?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a written local amendment disallowing it there is no reason this would be unsafe or prohibited. I have seen and worked on many, many basements that fit this exact description.

My only concern would be keeping the area clear of lint from the dryer.

Comment: Thanks. Is venting outside the house and periodical cleaning not enough? What other things can be placed in the room to make it clear of lint and prevent fire?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. Make sure the venting system (ducts, hoses, flapper, etc) are all in good shape and sealed  and connected well.